# как отодвинуть картинку awesome от текста. html css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

картинка пристыкована к тексту, на между ними сделать пробел?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Bootstrap
------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Grid xxxl */
.col-xxxl,
.col-xxxl-auto,
.col-xxxl-12,
.col-xxxl-11,
.col-xxxl-10,
.col-xxxl-9,
.col-xxxl-8,
.col-xxxl-7,
.col-xxxl-6,
.col-xxxl-5,
.col-xxxl-4,
.col-xxxl-3,
.col-xxxl-2,
.col-xxxl-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .col-xxxl {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .row-cols-xxxl-1 > * {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .row-cols-xxxl-2 > * {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .row-cols-xxxl-3 > * {
    flex: 0 0 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }

  .row-cols-xxxl-4 > * {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }

  .row-cols-xxxl-5 > * {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
  }

  .row-cols-xxxl-6 > * {
    flex: 0 0 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-1 {
    flex: 0 0 8.3333333333%;
    max-width: 8.3333333333%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-2 {
    flex: 0 0 16.6666666667%;
    max-width: 16.6666666667%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-3 {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-5 {
    flex: 0 0 41.6666666667%;
    max-width: 41.6666666667%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-6 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-7 {
    flex: 0 0 58.3333333333%;
    max-width: 58.3333333333%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-8 {
    flex: 0 0 66.6666666667%;
    max-width: 66.6666666667%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-9 {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-10 {
    flex: 0 0 83.3333333333%;
    max-width: 83.3333333333%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-11 {
    flex: 0 0 91.6666666667%;
    max-width: 91.6666666667%;
  }

  .col-xxxl-12 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .container,
  .container-lg,
  .container-md,
  .container-sm,
  .container-xl,
  .container-xxl,
  .container-xxxl {
    max-width: 1536px;
  }
}


/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  width: 16.6666666667%;
}

.navbar-logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Dropdown */
.dropdown-toggle:after {
  border: 0;
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
}


/* Forms */
.form-group:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}


/* Common
------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Content */
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding-top: 112px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 40px 0 0;
}


/* Header */
.header {
  height: 112px;
}

.header__top {
  background-color: #343434;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
}

.header__bottom {
  background-color: #4B4B4B;
  height: 72px;
}


/* Social */
.social {
  display: flex;
}

.social__link {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #5A5A5A;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 24px;
}

.social__link:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}


/* cover */
.cover {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.cover__content {
    padding: 60px 0;
}

/* text_rotate */

.text_rotate {
    transform: rotate(-10.61deg);
  margin-top: 61px;
}

/* icon */

.icon {
  color: #5A5A5A;
}

.favorites_img {
  height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.btn {
  width:100%;
}

/* footer */
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #343434;
  /* padding: 74px 0 25px 104px; */
}

.footer__top {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 82px 0;
}

.footer__bottom {
  padding-bottom: 28px;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-item {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav-item a {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= 'css/style.css' . '?' . filemtime('css/style.css') ?>" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <footer class="footer">
                <div class="footer__top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <nav class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-auto">
                                Контакты
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i><span> +7 (495) 980 0000</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> info@mail.ru</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> адрес</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="social">
                                        <a href="#" class="social__link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="social__link"><i class="fab fa-vk"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="social__link"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="social__link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет про меню, то добавьте следующий стиль:

```
.nav-link .fas {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```